# How to use log4j to see into Jersey

Tags: java, log4j, jersey

I'm new to log4j and am trying to use it to better understand why my resource is providing a `415 Media Type Not Supported` header.

I'm using the following:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.com.sun.jersey=DEBUG,stdout
```

This **seems** like it should work but I'm showing nothing in the console about the POST reaching this application.  I know it is reaching the application because if I turn the application off, the POSTer throws a "connection refused" when trying to POST.

Comment: Do you see other logging information? 

Not sure about your logging problem but your Jersey problem is most likely that you are missing accept or content-type header in your request and your service requires a specific one.

Comment: No, I don't see anything about the request.  That's why I'm trying to enable logging for it. :-\

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I couldn't get logging to work, but I was able to determine how to get the ContentType which is what I needed.  I had to add this to my class...

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;

@PostConstruct
public void myfunc() {
    if (uriInfo == null) { //breakpoint on this line, so I can see what uriInfo is

    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "How to use log4j to see into Jersey?" in any way.

Answer (score 10):

I'm afraid it's not as straightforward as adding the Jersey packages to your Log4J config. Jersey does not use Log4J internally; instead it uses [Java logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).

If you prefer to work with Log4J then your option is to configure Java logging to use the [SLF4JBridgeHandler](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) as a logging handler.

Typically this is done by specifying a logging properties file via JVM property, and adding handlers to the properties file, like so:

1. specify the logging properties file

   `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties`
2. add the `SLF4JBridgeHandler` as a logging handler in the `logging.properties` file

   ```
   handlers=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
   ```

SLF4J can then bind to Log4J, and you can then use your `log4j.properties` as usual to specify the logging level for Jersey classes.

As an aside, my advice -- if you're just doing this for quick-and-dirty debugging -- is to either:

1. attach a debugger to your application (assuming you have the application source code);
2. or work with Java logging directly. To [configure Java logging to output to a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html), add the following to your `logging.properties` file as specified earlier --

   ```
   com.sun.jersey.level=DEBUG
   com.sun.jersey.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
   java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=/path/to/debugging.log
   java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I only enabled log4j because I thought it would offer the ability for me to debug jersey better.  How can I view more details about the request without using log4j?  My concern is that currently NOTHING shows up in the application console from any kind of logging when the system throws the 415 header.

Comment: I have a debugger attached, and it shows nothing.  I thought log4j might provide more debugging/logging options.

Comment: I have updated my answer as I suspected you just wanted to do some quick-and-dirty debugging, in which case just work with Java logging directly.

Comment: I did attempt to add these lines to logging.properties and used the `ConsoleHandler` instead of `FileHandler`, but didn't see any output in my log.  I found a workaround, thanks for the help.  +1

Answer (score 6):

You can use `JUL to SLF4J Bridge` for this first add it to your classpath. You can use this if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Add those lines to a static initializer block or in your main method:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

Now you can control the jersey logs from your `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.category.org.glassfish.jersey=WARN,stdout
```

Comment: +1 for the static initializer for configuring the SLF4JBridgeHandler which in our case means less moving parts

Comment: Great answer, should be the checked one

Answer (score 0):

you can see on
[here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-initialize-log4j-in-a-web-application.html)
it's run
you must configure your

- web.xml
- log4j.properties
- Log4JInitServlet.java
- Log4JTestServlet.java

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice in this answer to create a custom logging feature class and register it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443054/1462479

Then modified the logger that it's using to be log4j.