# Using custom logging filter with LoggingFeature for Jersey Client.

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using Jersey 2.22. I have registered a `LoggingFeature` that logs requests, responses, headers, payload, etc based on the verbosity that I set however I would like to implement my own custom logging filter that this feature will use.

Looking at the source of `LoggingFeature`, it doesn't appear this is possible. This seems very inflexible. With previous versions of Jersey, it was very simple to implement a `LoggingFilter` and register it on the client.

I'd really like to implement my own version of `ClientLoggingFilter` so I can write a neat line to my log.

Any suggestions? The documentation is lacking IMO. https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html#d0e15744

Comment: you question is very broad, can you be more specific, what are you looking to log and using what exactly, how about code showing what you've already attempted?

Comment: I haven't attempted anything because from what I can tell you can't extend/implement you're own response filter the way you could with a LoggingFilter due to the LoggingFeature being in the way. I want to log aspects of the request/response the same way the default filter logs but would like it formatted to my needs. I could show code of how I'm registering the logging feature which works but after that I don't see a path forward. I think I'm missing something something.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you mean that you would like to format log message as per your needs ?

Comment: Basically, I want to extend the LoggingFeature the same way we were able to extend the LoggingFilter in Jersey 1.x. Both of these classes implemented the ClientRequest/ResponseFilters meaning they had access to the raw request and response objects. Things like headers, status, payload, response time, etc. Pretty common stuff if you're familiar with LoggingFilter/Feature in Jersey.

Comment: I have posted the solution on a similar question, link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171273/how-to-print-server-responses-using-loggingfeature-in-dropwizard-1-0-2/51443054#51443054

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to implement my own version of a LoggingFeature with a custom request/response container injected. Within the container I did the exact logging that we required.

Seems like a step backwards not being able to implement a simple filter and apply it to the client for things like custom logging.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001313/maven-dependecy-for-loggingfilter-in-jersey this is no longer possible.  Do you have an updated approach?