# Maven dependecy for LoggingFilter in Jersey

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey

What dependency must be added to pom.xml for class org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter? I try to add artifactId jersey-common and jersey-client from org.glassfish.jersey.core but in thats not exist this class.

Answer (score 11):

Since Jersey 2.23, you should use [`LoggingFeature`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html) instead of `LoggingFilter` (which has been removed in Jersey 2.26). Ensure that you have the `jersey-common` artifact in the classpath.

See the [documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html) for details.